# setTimout with Javascript for automation

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation

I have tried to use a `window.setTimeout` but I get an error at runtime:

> Error on line 182: TypeError: window.setTimeout is not a function. (In
>
> ```
> window.setTimeout(function(){
>
> }, 3000);
> ```
>
> ,`window.setTimeout` is undefined) (-2700)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: Fairly descriptive error message. So you do not have setTimeOut in JXA - perhaps delay() will work

Comment: Or remove the window. from it since there is no window

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ alert("working"); }, 1000);  I have tried to run it in Apple script Editor and I get the same error: Error on line 1: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setTimeout

Comment: https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/issues/19

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes: that's impressive for a correction. PS: humans are not compilers ;)

Answer (score 8):

First, JXA does not have `window` as the global object because it is not a browser.
You can access the global object via the top level `this` or, more simply, omit the global object to access the global variables and functions directly.

```
this.Math.sin(1)
// or
Math.sin(1)
```

Second, JXA has no support for `setTimeout` currently.
This is the essential reason why you got the error that `setTimeout` is undefined.

However, you can emulate `setTimeout` with [its Objective-C bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW17).
This is an example implementation of `setTimeout` with [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimer?language=objc).
Note that working with `NSTimer` in JXA requires to start `NSRunLoop` manually.

```
function timer (repeats, func, delay) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2, -1)
  args.unshift(this)
  var boundFunc = func.bind.apply(func, args)
  var operation = $.NSBlockOperation.blockOperationWithBlock(boundFunc)
  var timer = $.NSTimer.timerWithTimeIntervalTargetSelectorUserInfoRepeats(
    delay / 1000, operation, 'main', null, repeats
  )
  $.NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop.addTimerForMode(timer, "timer")
  return timer
}

function invalidate(timeoutID) {
  timeoutID.invalidate
}

var setTimeout = timer.bind(undefined, false)
var setInterval = timer.bind(undefined, true)
var clearTimeout = invalidate
var clearInterval = invalidate


setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(123)
}, 1000)

$.NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop.runModeBeforeDate("timer", $.NSDate.distantFuture)
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a global `delay(seconds)` function you can call.

```
...
delay(0.2);
...
```

See: https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/System-Events#example-of-sending-copy-command

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing asynchronous in JXA.  You can use `delay(3)`, but nothing else executes.

You can fire off another task with `$.system("yourCommand &")`, it runs asynchronously. Here is a little demo that speaks asynchronously. It could be another script that does whatever you need

```js
ObjC.import("stdlib")
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
$.system("(sleep 2;say hurry up!)&") // see the difference when you remove the &
prompt("are you ready?", "yes")
function prompt(text, defaultAnswer) {
  var options = { defaultAnswer: defaultAnswer || "" }
  try {
    return app.displayDialog(text, options).textReturned
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. But the delayed call fires a system call and I wanted to refresh the UI of my app with a delay (or the JS setInterval). Good to now that there is nothing asynchronous in JXA.

Comment: I guess your only alternative is the blocking delay(2). As an asynchronous kinda guy I found it distasteful.